# Java Connect Four in console - Horizontal and Vertical winning conditions

Tags: java

I'm working on a Connect Four game for the console in Java. I have problems with the winning conditions, as I don't know how to program them. Here is my code my Main:

```
public class Main {

public static char[] playerNumber = new char[]{'1', '2'};
public static char[] Badge = new char[]{'X', 'O'};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int moves = 7 * 6;
    int whichPlayer = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.println("                    FOUR IN A ROW");
    System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to the amazing game Four In A Row:");
    System.out.println("Enter a number between 0 and 6 for choosing a column.");
    System.out.println();

        Board board = new Board();
        board.fillBoard();
        board.presentBoard();

        do {
            // 1. get a badge
            char Player = playerNumber[whichPlayer];
            char badge = Badge[whichPlayer];

            // 2. make a turn
            board.makeTurn(badge, Player);
            board.presentBoard();

            // 3. Tjek om der er vinder
            if (board.checkWinHorizontal() || board.checkWinVertical()) {
                System.out.println("Player " + Player + " has won!");
                break;
            }

            // 4. change the player
            whichPlayer = 1 - whichPlayer;

            // 5. decrease moves
            --moves;

            if (moves == 0) {
                System.out.println("Game over, nobody has won.");
                System.out.println("Do you want to play again? 'Y' or 'N':");
                String newGame = scanner.nextLine();
                if (newGame.equals("Y") || newGame.equals("y")) {
                    break;
                }
                if (newGame.equals("N") || newGame.equals("n")) {
                    System.out.println("Thanks for the game!");
                    return;
                }
            }
            // 6. repeat
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

And here is my code for my Board class:

```
public class Board {

char[][] board = new char[6][7];

int column;

// Fills the empty spaces
public void fillBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

// Prints the board
public void presentBoard() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        System.out.print("            | ");
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("            -----------------------------");
        System.out.println();
    }
}

// Turn
public void makeTurn(char badge, char Player) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        // 1. Ask for a column
        System.out.println("Player " + Player + " turn: ");
        column = scanner.nextInt();

        // 2. Check if it's between 0 and 6
        if (column > 6) {
            System.out.println("That is not a valid number. Please enter a number between 0 and 6: ");
            continue;
        }

        // 3. Place a badge
        for (int i = 6 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (board[i][column] == ' ') {
                board[i][column] = badge;
                return;
            }
        }

        // If column is full
        System.out.println("Column " + column + " is full. Try another column:");

    } while (true);
}

// Check for vertical win
public boolean checkWinVertical() {
            return verticalWin(5, column);
    }

// Check for horizontal win
public boolean checkWinHorizontal() {
    return horizontalWin(5,column);
}

// Conditions for vertical win
private boolean verticalWin(int x, int y) {
    char charToCheck = board[x][y];
    if (board[x-1][y] == charToCheck &&
        board[x-2][y] == charToCheck &&
        board[x-3][y] == charToCheck) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
    }

// Conditions for horizontal win
private boolean horizontalWin(int x, int y) {
    char charToCheck = board[x][y];
    if (board[x][y+1] == charToCheck &&
            board[x][y+2] == charToCheck &&
            board[x][y+3] == charToCheck) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have succeeded in getting the game recognize a win horizontally and vertically at the bottom row of my array, but I don't know how to make the game recognize for the whole array. I'm only concentrating about the horizontal and vertical, as the diagonal is too complicated for me. And I don't know if this is the right approach or there is a better one.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by how you can succeed in checking for win conditions, but not for the whole array? Sometimes a check for a horizontal or vertical win fails, even though there is a horizontal or vertical win?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another solution.  It's the same general idea as previously mentioned: loop through each row/column, checking for a streak of 4 in a row.  Maybe this implementation will provide some other insight.  Below, I've shown an example method checking the horizontal streaks.  For vertical, you would iterate over the rows in the inner for loop instead.

```
public boolean checkWin(char badge) {
    return checkHorizontalStreaks(board, badge)
            || checkVerticalStreaks(board, badge);
}

private boolean checkHorizontalStreaks(char[][] board, char badge) {
    for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++) {
        // loop throught each row
        int currentStreak = 0;
        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++) {
            // loop through each column in the row
            if (board[row][col] == badge) {
                // keep the streak of 'badge' going
                currentStreak++;
                if (currentStreak == 4) {
                    // winner
                    return true;
                }
            } else {
                // restart the streak
                currentStreak = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

And then update your Main class with

```
        if (board.checkWin(badge)) {
            System.out.println("Player " + Player + " has won!");
            break;
        }
```

I'd wager there is a more efficient way to determine a winner (perhaps by treating the grid as a graph and traversing it with some special logic).  However, I suspect this may be enough for what you need.  I'll spare you the output, but it worked with a few different test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you could check all the adjacent fields around the last played field, so after the user did his turn. So for checking upwards you could do this:

```
    public boolean checkUp(int rowPlayed, int columnPlayed){
        boolean checked = false;
        if(rowplayed + 1 <= maxrows){ //Checks if you didn't hit the top
            if(board[rowPlayed+1][columnPlayed] != null){
                if(board[rowPlayed+1][columnPlayed].getPlayer() == currentPlayer){
                    checked =  true;
                }
            }
        }
        return checked;
    }
```

and for example implemented like this:

```
    public void checkWin(int rowPlayed, int columnPlayed){
        boolean checkingWin = true;
        int countWin = 0;
        while(checkingWin){
            if(checkUp(rowPlayed + countWin, columnPlayed)){
                countWin++;
            }
            else{
                checkingWin = false;
            }
            if(countWin == 4){
                checkinWin = false;
                //Insert win confirmation here
            }
        }
    }
```

It's partially pseudo code because I don't know exactly how you handle things in your code, nor do I know if this is the best way to do it. But I hope it was of help for you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a long answer and I'll go around the houses a bit so you can see how I reached my solution (which also expands to diagonal checking at the end).

I would use the last piece added as a starting point and work from there since checking all combinations is exhaustive and unnecessary.

Given the row and column of the last piece added I need to decide what I need to achieve.

I already know that the current row and column has the piece of the colour I'm looking for so I can ignore that.

For horizontal matching, I want to check I want to checking pieces to left and right in the same row have the same colour, and stop if the colour is different or there is no piece.

So imagine the following board (# = empty, R = Red piece, Y = Yellow piece:

```
6 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
5 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
4 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
3 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
2 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
1 #  #  #  #  #  #  #  #
0 Y  R  R  R  Y  Y  Y  R
  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7
```

The last move was Yellow, row 0, col 4.

So I want to check left and right from [0][4] and see if the total number of consecutive pieces of the colour is 3, (not 4) since I know [0][4] is Yellow and can be discounted.

Based on this I can take a recursive approach where I check the adjacent to one side, then recursively do the same thing as long as I keep matching pieces of the same colour or do not encounter an empty slot.

I'll start of with a check to the right (to demonstrate):

```
private static final int COLS = 7;
private static final int ROWS = 6;
public enum Piece {RED, YELLOW}; // null is empty

private Piece[][] board = new Piece[ROWS][COLS]; // the board

private int checkRight(Piece piece, int row, int col) {
    // assume valid row for now
    col++; // moving col to the right
    if (col >= COLS || board[row][col] != piece) {
       // We're outside the limits of the column or the Piece doesn't match
       return 0; // So return 0, nothing to add
    } else {
        // otherwise return 1 + the result of checkRight for the next col
        return 1 + checkRight(piece, row, col);
    }
}
```

Now I can perform the same to the left.

```
private int checkLeft(Piece piece, int row, int col) {
    // assume valid row for now
    col--; // moving col to the left
    if (col < 0 || board[row][col] != piece) {
       // We're outside the limits of the column or the Piece doesn't match
       return 0; // So return 0, nothing to add
    } else {
        // otherwise return 1 + the result of checkLeft for the next col
        return 1 + checkLeft(piece, row, col);
    }
}
```

And to check a winner for horizontal, I could do this:

```
public boolean checkWinner(Piece piece, int row, int col) {
    // if the sum is 3, we have a winner (horizontal only).
    return checkRight(piece, row, col) + checkLeft(piece, row, col) == 3;
}
```

**Ugh, there's a lot of repetition isn't there?**

We can condense the two methods into one by introducing a new parameter `direction` which can change if we move col positive or negative through the values 1 and -1 respectively:

```
private int check(Piece piece, int row, int col, int direction) {
    col += direction; // direction is either 1 (right) or -1 (left)
    if (col < 0 || col >= COLS || board[row][col] != piece) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1 + check(piece, row, col);
    }
}
```

Update `checkWinner()` for this new parameter:

```
private static final int POSITIVE = 1; // right at the moment
private static final int NEGATIVE = -1; // left at the moment

public boolean checkWinner(Piece piece, int row, int col) {
    // if the sum is 3, we have a winner (horizontal only).
    return check(piece, row, col, POSITIVE) + check(piece, row, col, NEGATIVE) == 3;
}
```

Now I could implement the same sort of logic for vertical, but instead stay on the same `col` and change the `row`. I will skip this part in detail and move onto a solution which includes this and diagonal checking.

This has been done using an `enum` called `CheckType` storing values for which `row` and `col` should change and is used by the `check()` method. e.g. for `HORIZONTAL` the column changes by 1 or -1 (depending upon the direction specified when `check()` is called) and the row remains 0.

```
public class Board {

    public enum Piece {

        RED, YELLOW
    };

    private enum CheckType {

        HORIZONTAL(0, 1), VERTICAL(1, 0), DIAGNONAL_UP(1, 1), DIAGNONAL_DOWN(-1, 1);

        int row;
        int col;

        CheckType(int row, int col) {
            this.row = row;
            this.col = col;
        }
    }

    private static final int POSITIVE = 1;
    private static final int NEGATIVE = -1;

    private static final int ROWS = 6;
    private static final int COLS = 7;

    private Piece[][] board = new Piece[ROWS][COLS];
    private boolean hasWinner = false;

    public boolean hasWinner() {
        return hasWinner;
    }

    private void checkWinner(Piece piece, int row, int col) {
            // check all values of enum CheckType for a winner
        // so HORIZONTAL, VERTICAL, etc..
        int enumIndex = 0;
        while (!hasWinner && enumIndex < CheckType.values().length) {
            hasWinner = check(piece, row, col, POSITIVE, CheckType.values()[enumIndex])
                    + check(piece, row, col, NEGATIVE, CheckType.values()[enumIndex]) == 3;
            enumIndex++;
        }
    }

    private int check(Piece piece, int row, int col, int direction, CheckType type) {
        row += type.row * direction;
        col += type.col * direction;
        if (row >= ROWS || row < 0 || col >= COLS || col < 0 || board[row][col] != piece) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1 + check(piece, row, col, direction, type);
        }
    }

    // for completeness, adding a Piece    
    public boolean add(Piece piece, int col) {
        int row = 0;
        while (row < ROWS && board[row][col] != null) {
            row++;
        }
        if (row < ROWS) {
            board[row][col] = piece;
            // check for winner after successful add
            checkWinner(piece, row, col);
        }
        return row < ROWS;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.